# PDEs on metric space?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces

Is it possible to pose a PDE on a metric space instead of normed space? For example in Banach spaces, the usual example is
$$u_t - \Delta u = 0$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
where it turns out that $u \in H^1(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$, and the equation holds in $L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$.

Is it sensible to write
$$u_t - Au = f$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
where the first equality only holds on some metric space instead of some Banach space? Where can I find more details?

Of course we don't need norms for convergence so I thought maybe things can be weakened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't my area of study, but one thing that immediately came to mind is that if your metric space admits a suitably-behaved [metric derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_derivative) then certain aspects of the theory of differential equations ought to generalize. [Here's an article](http://www.emis.de/journals/MB/127.2/mb127_2_22.pdf) that might interest you. And [here's an entire textbook](http://my.fit.edu/~gtenali/lakshmibook.pdf).

Bear in mind that the "classical" theory is formulated in the language of linear structure. Since a general metric space need not be linearizable in the ordinary sense that the derivative linearizes functions on Euclidean space, some of the more convenient aspects of the theory might be absent in the not-necessarily-Euclidean metric space setting. Hopefully someone with a more specialized interest in this subject can provide more details.